# Define variable before all JUnit Tests start running?

Tags: java, junit

I have some code that I want to run before all @Tests in a Junit file.  This code will call a TCPServer, get some data, convert it into a usable format (i.e., string) and THEN I want tests to run on top of that.  I can call the server in each test, but after two tests the server stops responding.  How would I do something like that?  This is essentially what I have so far:

```
public class Test {
    public Terser getData() throws Exception {
        // Make the connection to PM.service
        TCPServer tc = new TCPServer();
        String [] values = tc.returnData();

        // Make the terser and return it.  
        HapiContext context = new DefaultHapiContext();
        Parser p = context.getGenericParser();
        Message hapiMsg = p.parse(data);
        Terser terser = new Terser(hapiMsg);
        return terser;
    }

    @Test
    public void test_1() throws Exception {
        Terser pcd01 = getData();
        // Do Stuff
    }

    @Test
    public void test_2() throws Exception {
        Terser pcd01 = getData();
        // Do Stuff
    }

    @Test
    public void test_3() throws Exception {
        Terser pcd01 = getData();
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

I tried using @BeforeClass, but the terser didn't remain in scope.  I am very much a Java newbie, so any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the @BeforeClass version that you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your `Terser` a field of your class, as follows:

```
public class Test {
    static Terser pcd01 = null;
    @BeforeClass
    public static void getData() throws Exception {
        // Make the connection to PM.service
        TCPServer tc = new TCPServer();
        String [] values = tc.returnData();

        // Make the terser and return it.  
        HapiContext context = new DefaultHapiContext();
        Parser p = context.getGenericParser();
        Message hapiMsg = p.parse(data);
        pcd01 = new Terser(hapiMsg);
    }
    @Test
    public void test_1() throws Exception {
        // Do stuff with pcd01
    }

    @Test
    public void test_2() throws Exception {
        // Do stuff with pcd01
    }

    @Test
    public void test_3() throws Exception {
        // Do stuff with pcd01
    }
}
```

In this setup, `getData` is run only once before all of your tests, and it intializes your `Terser pcd01` as specified.  You can then use `pcd01` in each test as the scope of fields make them available to all methods in the class.

Comment: This won't compile.  `@BeforeClass` must be on a static method. `pcd01` must also be static.

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm!